# Facebook OG debug Curl Error : WRITE_ERROR

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm at a complete loss here: The Facebook debugger won't scrape this website: http://kalect.com.au/. Fetch new scrape information returns 2 errors

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

The Open Graph tags are showing when you view code in a browser and other OG testers can see the tags. Its only Facebook that can't see them/errors.

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="http://kalect.com.au/images/website/facebook-like.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://kalect.com.au/" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Kalect" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="KALECT is about bringing fun, quirky and unique home &amp; lifestyle products to the table. It is an inspiration of everything interiors that you should know about. A collection of quality Australian labels " />
  <meta property="og:title" content="KALECT - creating your kind of beautiful - Kalect - home wares" />
```

Comment: There seem to be issues with how your server delivers the content; the W3C Validator can’t process your site either, http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://kalect.com.au/ – it says, _“A fatal error occurred when attempting to decode response body from http://kalect.com.au/. Either we do not support the content encoding specified ("x-gzip"), or an error occurred while decoding it. The error was: Can't gunzip content: Header Error: Bad Magic”_

Answer (score 0):

@CBroe - Thanks for your assistance. The site is built using Joomla and gzip is disabled and confirmed using http://checkgzipcompression.com/.

I when though every component looking for other compression options and found one buried inside one of the Joomla Extensions called "Mijo Shop" disabling the components built in compression fixed the problem.

A fresh set of eyes always helps - Thanks