# Facebook - Curl Error : WRITE_ERROR Failed writing body

Tags: wordpress, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, elementor

I have Wordpress website with elementor and every time.

When I'm fetching scrape information for Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger it ends with this error - Curl Error : WRITE_ERROR Failed writing body (5077 != 8725)

I found this topic ([Facebook OG debug Curl Error : WRITE_ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31396312/facebook-og-debug-curl-error-write-error)) but our website looks ok with w3.org validator.

Sadly I didn't find what this error means with FB scraper.

Does anybody have idea what that means?

Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: `(5077 != 8725)` sounds like there might be an issue with a wrong `Content-Length` header.